# Xcode = "Swift stdlib Tool Error"

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift3

When I try to run my app in iPhone 5 (I have Xcode 9.2 and iOS 10.3.3) appears "Swift sodlib tool Error … Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {…"

/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DBG-apryihmbeylkqnbsxrtvzxistsoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DBG.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
    /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign' '92CDBC9AD74FA4FC6FE92D8FF8B9AA763901AE1D' '--verbose' '/Users/d/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DBG-apryihmbeylkqnbsxrtvzxistsoq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DBG.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'

So how can I fix this? I already try change certificate , change version , change everything . =/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently. While in Xcode, try cleaning the project (Cmd + Shift + K), once finished, run the project. After that, a window popped up asking for access to keychain, I put my Mac's password, selected "Always Allow" and the problem went away.

Let me know if this helps.